# The set of all symmetric polynomials with integer coefficients and variables $r_1,...,r_n$ is a subring of $\Bbb Z [r_1,...,r_n]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to prove that if $S$ is the set of all symmetric polynomials of integer coefficients and variables $r_1,...,r_n$ then it is a subring of $\Bbb Z [r_1,...,r_n]$.

I figured I could take the approach of using the subring test.

I would have to show $S$ is not empty. It contains the zero polynomial at least so it is not empty.

Next I would show that if we have $\rho \in S_n, \rho(f) = f(r_{\rho(1)},...,r_{\rho(n)}),$ then for all $f,g \in \Bbb Z[r_1,...,r_n]$. $\rho (fg) = \rho(f) \rho(g) \in S.$ So,

Finally I would show that $\rho (f+ (-g)) = \rho(f) +\rho(-g) \in S.$

I'm not sure if I am thinking about this correctly. Secondly the notation is confusing me so I don't really know how to perform the necessary checks. How would I represent $f(r_{\rho(1)},...,r_{\rho(n)}) + (-g(r_{\rho(1)},...,r_{\rho(n)}))$ and $f(r_{\rho(1)},...,r_{\rho(n)})(g(r_{\rho(1)},...,r_{\rho(n)}))?$ Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're a bit confused about what you're trying to prove.  Remember that by definition, $f\in S$ means that $\rho(f)=f$ for all $\rho\in S_n$. And you want to prove that if $f,g\in S$ then $fg\in S$ and $f-g\in S$.  So what you want to prove is that if $\rho(f)=f$ and $\rho(g)=g$ for all $\rho\in S_n$, then $\rho(fg)=fg$ for all $\rho\in S_n$, and similarly for differences.  Try proving this; it shouldn't be too hard.  You don't need to write out what $\rho(f)$ actually is; you can just use the fact that $\rho$ is a ring-homomorphism.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. My book gave us a pretty ambiguous hint and I probably over thought it.